# Javascript other function every click

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm new to JavaScript and i want to call another function every time, like:

```
onclick="on first click a(), then b(), etc "
```

Of course it won't work like this but is there an option to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: A counter is all you need

Comment: I don't think he can use jQuery yet, as he said, he's just started with JS. Let him learn the very basics first before using a huge library like jQuery. In other words: Let him feel the pain of VanillaJS :)

Comment: Apart from Sascha's answer, you could let every called function change the onclick binding after being called.

Comment: Haha you're right Sascha :-)

Answer (score 3):

Store the functions in a sensible data structure. Since you want to access them sequentially, make it an array.

```
function a() { };
function b() { };
function c() { };
function d() { };

var myFunctions = [a, b, c, d];
```

Then track which function you want to call next:

```
var nextFunction = 0;
```

Then, each time you call one of the functions, increment the pointer.

```
function myFunctionSwitcher() {
    myFunctions[nextFunction]();
    nextFunction = nextFunction + 1;
}
```

Then, use that as the event handler:

```
document.getElementById('whatever').addEventListener('click', myFunctionSwitcher);
```

Add some logic to reset `nextFunction` to `0` when it gets to the end of the array.

Comment: Could you make an end result for me? Thanks for your answer btw!

Comment: @user2514005 — Aside from resetting the `nextFunction` (which is just an if greater than length assign 0), that *is* the end result.

Comment: Again, that *is* an example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course there is. Always call the same function and let the called function decide what happens next:

```
<script>
  var count = 0;
  function myClickHandler() {
    switch(count) {
      case 0:
        a();
        break;
      case 1:
        b();
        break;
    }
    count++;
  }
</script>
<div onclick="myClickHandler()"></div>
```

Of course, this is the most readable beginner version of that. See Quentin's answer for a more advanced example.

Comment: Yours isn't more "beginner..." It's messier and it smells with all of those cases/breaks

Comment: Don't hate the player, hate the game.

Comment: I'm assuming you're saying that I should hate Javascript? It's you who's using it in this grotesque manner...

Comment: I mean that there are cleaner solutions for switch case-style statements, like in CoffeeScript. Nevertheless, it's right, switch statements are ugly in any language.

Comment: My point is you shouldn't call this a "beginner version" of Quentin's answer. Quentin's answer is extremely rudimentary, as is yours. Yours isn't a beginner version, it's a messy-code, bad-practice *equivalent*, but definitely not a version.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution one

#### HTML

```
<button>Click me</button>
```

#### Javascript

```
// array of functions
var functions = [
    function () { alert("First function") },
    function () { alert("Second function") },
    function () { alert("Third function") },
    function () { alert("Clicked more than three times.") }
];

// all buttons
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

// the counter
var i = -1;

// detect the click for first button
anchors[0].onclick = function() {    
    // call the functions using i variable
    if (i < 3) {
        // increment i
        functions[++i]();
    }
    else {
        functions[3]();
    }
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fgmB2/1/)

---

### Solution two

I recommend to use in HTML a `data-*` attribute, for example `data-func`.

#### HTML

```
<button data-func="0">1</button>
<button data-func="1">2</button>
```

#### Pure Javascript

```
// an array of functions
var functions = [
    function () { alert("First function") },
    function () { alert("Second function") }
];

// all buttons
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

// detect click for each button
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    var anchor = anchors[i];
    anchor.onclick = function() {
        // get data-func attribute
        var foo = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-func"));
        // run the function from array
        functions[foo]();
    }
}
```